# Android SDK Manager Error

Tags: 13.04, android, eclipse, sdk

I keep geting this error when I run the update manager. Can anyone help me debug this?

> Stopping ADB server failed (code -1). Unable to run 'adb': Cannot run
> program
> "/home/lightning0/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/platform-tools/adb":
> error=2, No such file or directory. Starting ADB server failed (code
> -1).
>
> ls -l /home/lightning0/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/platform-tools/ad‌‌​​b: No such file or directory

Comment: Yes I am certain it exists. I don't think I have root privileges or something.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/106691702488567678641/posts/78hAVCcszgz

Comment: Edit your answer and provide the output of `ls -l $HOME/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/platform-tools/ad‌‌​​b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple, the file/directory do not exist where you say it does. Review the configuration files or how you are invoking the program and point to the right file.

Comment: I can prove that the file exists, plus.google.com/106691702488567678641/posts/78hAVCcszgz how do i point the file to the correct directory?

Comment: Thank you, I had to open nautilus file browser as root and make a link in my root directory pointing to the correct folder.