# android studio emulator adb problem

Tags: android, ubuntu-studio, android-studio, adb, android-sdk

I'm installing android studio for the first time on ubuntu machine

> OS: Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2
>
> CPU: 4 cores, G3, core i5, 1500
>
> RAM: 8GB
>
> BOIS: HP v2.90 PC

and when I try to start the emulator I find this

```
The emulator process for AVD Nexus_7_2012_API_19 has terminated.
```

[image: screenshot]

---

***adb.log***

```
--- adb starting (pid 3676) --- adb I 08-12 09:43:44  3676  3676 main.cpp:63] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 adb I 08-12 09:43:44 
3676  3676 main.cpp:63] Version 31.0.3-7562133 adb I 08-12 09:43:44 
3676  3676 main.cpp:63] Installed as
/home/dark/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb adb I 08-12 09:43:44  3676 
3676 main.cpp:63]  adb I 08-12 09:43:44  3676  3676 auth.cpp:417]
adb_auth_init... adb I 08-12 09:43:44  3676  3676 auth.cpp:152] loaded
new key from '/home/dark/.android/adbkey' with fingerprint
85035B085F7989AE48877D66995C7B2E9BCECC5CAAB100B1B871A95B049A56C4 adb I
08-12 09:43:44  3676  3676 auth.cpp:392] adb_auth_inotify_init...
--- adb starting (pid 4554) --- adb I 08-12 09:50:44  4554  4554 main.cpp:63] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 adb I 08-12 09:50:44 
4554  4554 main.cpp:63] Version 31.0.3-7562133 adb I 08-12 09:50:44 
4554  4554 main.cpp:63] Installed as
/home/dark/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb adb I 08-12 09:50:44  4554 
4554 main.cpp:63]  adb I 08-12 09:50:44  4554  4554 auth.cpp:417]
adb_auth_init... adb I 08-12 09:50:44  4554  4554 auth.cpp:152] loaded
new key from '/home/dark/.android/adbkey' with fingerprint
85035B085F7989AE48877D66995C7B2E9BCECC5CAAB100B1B871A95B049A56C4 adb I
08-12 09:50:44  4554  4554 auth.cpp:392] adb_auth_inotify_init... adb
server killed by remote request
--- adb starting (pid 4636) ---
```

---

these questions and answers didn't help me

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studio
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301960/errorunable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio
- [Android SDK Manager Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338022/android-sdk-manager-error)
- [ADB Android Studio Ubuntu ERROR : Unable to detect adb version, adb output: /home/hamid/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714653/adb-android-studio-ubuntu-error-unable-to-detect-adb-version-adb-output-hom)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1419201/unable-to-locate-adb-when-using-android-studio

---

**How to fix this error ?**

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the specific version of Ubuntu you’re running and, if possible, the CPU and amount of RAM installed on your system? This will make it easier to offer actionable advice 

Comment: > OS: Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2
>
> CPU: 4 cores, G3, core i5, 1500
>
> RAM: 8GB
>
> BOIS: HP v2.90 PC

Comment: Also can you show either `dmesg` or `journalctl` output for the same time as your last log to adb in the question. Also, how did you install?

Comment: Not now, but I installed it via snap and reinstalled via apt repo and same issue

Comment: Try running via cmd line w/ sudo. if it works, you need a group.

Comment: did you install adb tools as well? May have been a depend. check w/ `apt search adb tools`. If it doesn't say "installed" then you need it

Comment: `android-tools-adb/focal,focal,now 1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2 all [installed]`